# Macro with generic type in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to create macro in Rust that looks more or less like this:

```
macro_rules! custom_macro {
    ($gen: ident) => {
        let value: MyCustomType<$gen> = Deserialize::deserialize(data)?;

        // Some other code here.
    };
}
```

It somehow throws many error at first line, i.e., `let ...`, that `error: expected one of @ or |, found :`. Any ideas about this and how to solve it?

**EDIT:**

Here is a more complete example closely related to my use case:

```
macro_rules! custom_macro {
    ($gen: ident) => {
        let value: MyCustomType<$gen> = todo!();

        Ok(())
    };
}

struct MyCustomType<T>(T);
struct Inner;
struct Outer;

pub async fn my_func(flag: bool) -> Result<(), std::error::Error> {
    match flag {
        true => custom_macro!(Inner),
        false => custom_macro!(Outer),
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    my_func(true)
}
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=253a65d18ca574790132dd463a2b3997).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I updated your playground with the issue I face, and updated the question here to make it more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable in a match arm, where an expression is expected, without introducing a block (note the double `{{}}`):

```rust
macro_rules! custom_macro {
    ($gen: ident) => {{
        let value: MyCustomType<$gen> = todo!();

        Ok(())
    }};
}
```